# "Filter by color" has disappeared from my dropdown filter

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel sheet, and when using the data filters, Filter By Color is not available. There is definitely more than one color in the column I'm trying to filter on, so why isn't it showing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spreadsheet was in Sharing mode. For some reason, this removes Filter by color and Sort by color. I turned sharing mode off, and they returned.